# Mysql: How to check validity of order based on dates

Tags: mysql

Here is a sample data:

```
Key Start Date           Stop date              Order
1   2010-07-10 11:50:11  2011-10-20 9:10:59     1
1   2013-01-09 13:04:12  2013-03-11 13:42:25    2
1   2014-05-23 14:45:40  2015-10-16 8:53:54     3
1   2013-01-09 13:04:12  9999-12-31 0:00:00     4
2   2015-12-15 11:16:06  2016-12-15 11:16:06    1
2   2016-12-15 11:16:06  2017-12-15 11:16:06    2
2   2017-12-15 11:16:06  9999-12-31 0:00:00     3
```

I want to check whether the start and stop dates of a particular order do not invalidate another order for the same key. Only one order is possible within a start and stop range of date.

I want to write a MySQL query to print the key of all which have invalid order. 
Here in this example Key one has an invalid order as Order 2 and Order 4 are invalid. Is it possible to check this by MySQL query?

Comment: can you share your try query

Comment: Do you want conflicted order id's?

Comment: `Key one has an invalid order as Order 2...`. Why Order 2 for Key 1 is invalid ?

Comment: Why the key is not unique? does this table has a unique key for each row?

Comment: @OtoShavadze i meant order 4 is invalid as order 2 is already present.

Comment: @Kh.Taheri there is unique key as well not interested on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the rows that are out of order using:

```
select s.*
from sample s
where exists (select 1
              from sample s2
              where s2.key = s.key and
                    s2.startdate < s.startdate and
                    s2.order > s.order
             );
```

Note that `order` and `key` are SQL keywords, so they are very poor choices for column names.

Comment: but, the Key is not unique as shown in the sample data?

Comment: @Gordon, i just created a sample data to ask the question. Oops.